# How to test for another player in a radius

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a multiplayer minigame, I don't know how to test for another player in a radius, the command that i want is like when a player get near to another player in a radius of 3 then a command will run, `execute @a ~ ~ ~ testfor @a[r=*radius*]` don't help because it will just target you in it, add the `[c=*count*]` don't help me neither, because the command also return true if there's one match (and that's you)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it. Use the `rm` parameter, which specifies the minimum distance:

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ testfor @a[r=R,rm=RM]
```

Where RM is less then R, logically.

Or, if you would like to execute a command after this one returns true, combine them together:

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ execute @a[r=R,rm=RM] ~ ~ ~ /your-command
```

Comment: i've found it out at the night that i post this, thank anyway

Comment: @ĐặngQuốcTrung Thanks for coming back and marking this answer as accepted. By this you help future visitors.

Comment: yea i know :) Hope that everyone know to minecraft awesome commands to do some amazing things